# How to correctly use dependency injection in SignalR ASP.NET Core On-event handlers

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I am using a SignalR ASP.NET Core client that subscribes to SignalR ASP.NET Core server to receive and process messages. On startup of the client application I use a background service to start the connection to the server and register what should happen when a message is received on a specific method name. ([Link to source](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.Core/HubConnectionExtensions.cs), On-method on line 271)

The handling each of the incoming messages involves calling a Handler that returns a Task, which in turn has multiple dependencies and calls a database/an external API. Those dependencies are all injected using the default DI framework (IServiceProvider).

The problem is that I register the handler on application startup and thus resolve all it's dependencies at that moment. What I am seeing afterwards is that the memory-usage of my app keeps gradually increasing until it runs out of memory. After a lot of debugging I suspect the reason for this is that the DI framework/garbage collector does not clean everything up correctly after the handling of an incoming message is done. Why I have no idea.

Does this sound like a possible cause for my memory problem? Does anyone have some insights on how to handle incoming SignalR messages that trigger a load of other services/repositories that are injected using DI? Almost all of the examples I can find online are only logging a message to the console, which is not a very in-depth use case.

Comment: Can you show your code about DI?

Comment: We need to see some code.